# How to do an ItemReaderAdapter without initializingBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

In the final step of my job, it would be easier for me to call an existing DAO that would query and return a complex graph of object i need to persist with an ItemWriter as an XML.  I use XStream with annotation.

Every example of ItemReaderAdapter i see implements the initializingBean to initialize the collection of objects i need to iterate thru (Basically,do the query on the DB).

This would work great if my data would be in the DB when the afterPropertiesSet() is invoked(at the start of the job!), but the data i have to read is persisted in the steps of the current job.  How can i use ItemReaderAdapter in this case?

Summary:

step 1 : read an xml and write the objects in the DB (trxA)

step 2 : read a flatFile and write the object in the DB (trxB)

step 3 : business logic on trxA

step 4 : business logic on trxB

step 5 : (this is the one ;-)) call the DAO that will return an unifiedObject of trxA and trxB.

basically, i need to know : Is there a way i can tell my adapter to initialize at the start of the step instead of the start of the job?

Regards

Edit: to be clear, here is an example taken in a book

```
public class ProductServiceAdapter implements InitializingBean {
  private ProductService productService;
  private List<Product> products;
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
  this.products = productService.getProducts();
}
public Product nextProduct() {
  if (products.size()>0) {
    return products.remove(0);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

The DAO access is done in the afterPropertieSet() so it does not work in my case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. InitializingBean shouldn't start reading data, it should just ensure that the required dependencies are set. Does the DAO start reading data on creation or something?

Comment: @lckster see my edit.  in fact the data is read from the dao at startup, but only to return the result set as a collection.  then the nextProduct() method do the actual read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to do 'stuff' at the start of the step, use this and implement the beforeStep()

[StepExecutionListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/2.0.x/reference/html-single/index.html#stepExecutionListener)

and then you configure it like this

```
<step id="concreteStep">
<tasklet>
    <chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="5"/>
    <listeners>
        <listener class="com.Listener"/>
    <listeners>
</tasklet></step>
```

Comment: Oh great, i used a lot of listener (reader,processor writer) but missed this one!!... so i could auto wire my DAO there and call the init method!!!!  Thanks.  Exactly what i was looking for ;-)

Comment: correction: actually auto wire my adapter to call the init... not the DAO!!